# SQL - How to search the string that contains the "." (dot) in between the words?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the below `SQL` query:

```
Select * from temp-table where column-1 like '%' pipe gi '%'
```

I want to search the string which contains the "." (dot) in between.

Example: **G.i Pipes.**

Answer (score 0):

This is very odd or I would say very very specific question you ask. Also this is not search as you want because your input and output logic does not match to understand.

Check this example.

```
Declare @t table ([column-1] varchar(100))

insert into @t values ('g.i.pipes.'),('g i pipes' ), ('g.i pipes') , ('pipe.g.i'),  ('pipe.g.i.')

declare @v varchar(50) = 'pipe g i'

Select * from @t where [column-1] like '%' + REPLACE(@v, ' ','.') + '%'
```

One suggestion is never give column name as you given. Do not use - ' space etc.